# What is the difference between these 2 iptable rules?

Tags: iptables

I am learning about iptables and can't find an explanation about the difference between these 2 rules:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

What does the state "NEW" mean? If there is a state "NEW" is there a state "OLD" then?

Comment: There's ESTABLISHED

Comment: Here is where I found this http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/setting-up-iptables-for-ssl-port-443-a-821808/

Comment: @muru what is better to use? the first or the second rule?

Comment: Better for what?

Comment: to save as a rule in my iptables? is there a difference between those 2

Comment: I have also found this https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Security_Guide/s1-firewall-ipt-basic.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NEW is the state when the connection is first made.  It is common to ACCEPT all ESTABLISHED,RELATED connections early in the iptables rules to reduce the processing load.  Subsequent rules determine what NEW connections are allowed based on port number, etc.
For the two rules above, the first will allow all traffic in on port 80, while the second will only allow the initial handshake.  If the default rule was to DROP packets the second rule alone would be insufficient to allow communications on port 80.

Comment: OK that is exactly what I have...default DROP all for input...so i need to use the first rule in order for port 80 to work

Comment: The first rule is sufficient.  If you have a lot of ports that need opened it is more efficient to start by accepting all ESTABLISHED,RELATED traffic followed by a NEW rule for each port.  But if you're only opening port 80 simply use the first rule.